# Почему корутина выполняет код без ожидания?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

я запускаю корутину а она не ждет, а сразу выполняет код

код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class testScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(test());
    }

    IEnumerator test()
    {
        Debug.Log("tested");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(7f);
    }
}
```

Comment: чего именно она должна ждать? вывод в консоль написан сразу в методе, без всяких ожиданий

Comment: Всмысле? Там написанно "WaitForSeconds(7f);". Ну хорошо. Если я ошибся то можете написать образец кода?

Comment: ну написал WaitForSeconds, окей, только эта строка выполнится после `Debug.Log`, потому что исполнение кода идёт сверху вниз. А вот если поменять строки местами, тогда, логично, что будет ждать

Comment: Спасибо! Буду знать!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно поменять Debug.Log() и yield return new WaitForSeconds() местами

```
IEnumerator test()
{
    //Ждем 7 секунд и только потом выводим в консоль текст
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(7f);
    Debug.Log("tested");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне уже ответили)))

Comment: @kuzinAlexandr вам писали комментарий, а это ответ базы знаний, его можете принять, если считаете полезным. Он может оказаться полезным кому-то еще. Вопрос считается решенным, если у него есть принятый ответ.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373567/aepot галочку поставил